# How to combine multiple excel files into one using R

Tags: r, excel

As the title states. I have to download at least 30 excel files from an online database and it is a headache because I have to combine one by one , I would like to have a single excel file where every tap belongs to a different file, any suggestion?

For example: Excel Files
File1
File2
File 3
so on...

Combine these files into macroexcelfiles, and tap1 is file 1, tap2 is file2, and so on, so forth...

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach that avoids quite a bit of unnecessary looping:

```
library(openxlsx)
setwd("~/MyXLSXFiles/")
files <- list.files(pattern="xlsx")
files
#[1] "Bar.xlsx" "Foo.xlsx"

data <- setNames(lapply(files, read.xlsx), files)
write.xlsx(data, file = "Combined.xlsx")
```

Note also that the individual sheets are named based on the list `data`'s names.

[image: Final result workbook]

Comment: Thank yo sou much, this is the best answer. Ian, one question, when I open the excel file, it displays something like "xml:space="preserve">New Covers" , where "New Covers" is the original name of my columns, what should I do with the other part that was not in my original file_?

Comment: Thanks, thank you so much Ian, I used this solution!

Answer (score 2):

I use this code almost every day

```
library(openxlsx)

files <- list.files(pattern = ".xlsx")
wb <- createWorkbook()
for(file in files)) {
    df <- read.xlsx(file)
    addWorksheet(wb,file)
    writeData(wb,file,df)
}
saveWorkbook(wb,'combined.xlsx',overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! is there any line of code to get the list of all files name, to put into files <- c(<'grep files to list or enter each file name'>)?

Comment: I modified my answer. If the script and the excels are in the same directory that code should work.

Comment: It displays: Error: unexpected '{' in:
"    df <- read.xlsx(files[num])
    addWorksheet(wb,files{"

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover Upvote but isn't `files{num}` a typo? It should be `files[num]`

Comment: Or even simpler, `for(f in files)` then use `f` instead of `files[num]`.

Comment: Thanks Stefan! I really apreciate your help

Comment: Updated. Sorry for the typos.